# How to close a popup window in Liferay?

Tags: popup, liferay, liferay-6

I load the WebContent edit portlet on a Popup window using the following code:

```
<liferay-ui:icon
    image="edit"
    label="true"
    message="news-edit-url"
    url="${oneNews.newsEditUrl}"
    />
```

editUrl:

```
taglibEditURL = "javascript:Liferay.Util.openWindow({dialog: {width: 960}," + 
    "id: '" + renderResponse.getNamespace() + "'," +
    "title: '" + LanguageUtil.format(request.getLocale(), "edit-x", HtmlUtil.escape(assetRenderer.getTitle(request.getLocale()))) + "'," +
    "uri:'" + HtmlUtil.escapeURL(editPortletURLString) + "'});";
```

When the content is saved or published, the portlet is loaded on the popup window. I want the popup window to close and the portlet with the editURL link to refresh.

Any help regarding this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the code to close the pop-up, this should be present in the parent page which opens the pop-up:

***Liferay version 6.1***

```
Liferay.provide(
        window,
        '<portlet:namespace />closePopup',
        function(popupIdToClose) {

            var A = AUI();

            A.DialogManager.closeByChild('#' + popupIdToClose);
        },
        ['aui-base','aui-dialog','aui-dialog-iframe']
    );
```

***Liferay version 6.2***

```
Liferay.provide(
    window,
    '<portlet:namespace/>closePopup',
        function(popupIdToClose) {

            var popupDialog = Liferay.Util.Window.getById(popupIdToClose);

            popupDialog.destroy();
        },
        ['liferay-util-window']
    );
```

Here is the code to refresh the portlet which opened the pop-up. This should be present in the parent page which opens the pop-up:

```
Liferay.provide(
        window,
        '<portlet:namespace />refreshPortlet',
        function() {

            <%-- refreshing the portlet [Liferay.Util.getOpener().] --%>
            var curPortletBoundaryId = '#p_p_id<portlet:namespace />';

            Liferay.Portlet.refresh(curPortletBoundaryId);
        },
        ['aui-dialog','aui-dialog-iframe']
    );
```

It is up to you how to call the `closePopup` & `refreshPortlet` functions. One way is you can let the pop-up refresh and call the `closePopup` function from the pop-up itself only when the request is successfully processed and then call the `refreshPortlet` function also from the pop-up.

Here is a code-snippet which would help you to call parent-page functions from the pop-up:

```
Liferay.Util.getOpener().<portlet:namespace />closePopup(popupIdToClose);
Liferay.Util.getOpener().<portlet:namespace />refreshPortlet();
```

**The `popupIdToClose` is the same `id` which is used when opening the pop-up as shown:**

```
taglibEditURL = "javascript:"
                +   Liferay.Util.openWindow({"
                +       "dialog: {width: 960},"
                +       "id: '" + renderResponse.getNamespace() + "'," // This is the "popupIdToClose"
                +       "title: '" + LanguageUtil.format(request.getLocale(), "edit-x", HtmlUtil.escape(assetRenderer.getTitle(request.getLocale()))) + "',"
                +       "uri:'" + HtmlUtil.escapeURL(editPortletURLString)
                +       "'}"
                +   ");";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for yuor answer. Couldt you explain please, how can I call this methods within /html/portlet/journal/edit_article.jsp. I call this jsp from my portlet for editing and then publishing the news Article. I dont understand, how can I get popupIdToClose...

Comment: I try to call the functions:  AUI().use('event', 'node', function(A) {
   A.one(<portlet:namespace />publishButton)
    .on('click', function(e){
      Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup('<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() %>');
      });
     
 });

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try to call the functions: AUI().use('event', 'node', function(A) { A.one(<portlet:namespace />publishButton) .on('click', function(e){ Liferay.Util.getOpener() .closePopup('<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() %>'); }); }); I see the error: Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup('<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() %>') is not a function. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Two things could be wrong either one of them or both of them: 1) if you have declared the function as `<portlet:namespace />closePopup` and are calling as `Liferay.Util.getOpener().closePopup` then the syntax is not proper, so the call should be like this `Liferay.Util.getOpener().<portlet:namespace />closePopup`. 2) Also this call `Liferay.Util.getOpener()` is to call a function of the parent page, check if the function `closePopup` is declared in the pop-up or in the parent page.

Comment: closePopup is declared in the  parent page. Hier is my declaration: Liferay.provide( window, '<portlet:namespace />closePopup', function(popupIdToClose) {... and hier is my call Liferay.Util.getOpener().<portlet:namespace />closePopup('<%=renderResponse.getNamespace() %>'); After function call: TypeError: Liferay.Util.getOpener()._15_closePopup is not a function

Comment: Try to check what type of function is created in the parent-page by viewing source in the browser. Are the pop-up and parent page different portlets? if yes, then either pass your `portletId` (`<portlet:namespace />`)  to the pop-up or just remove the `<portlet:namespace />` from the declaration & call, so that the call and the declaration are both same.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Now, I can call both functions, and refresh method works, but if i call  the closePopup() funktion I see this error: TypeError: A.one(child) is null
A.one(child).ancestor(DOT + CSS_DIALOG, true).

Answer (score 1):

AUI taglib solution for 6.2 version. No additional JS required.

```
<aui:button cssClass="close-panel" type="cancel" value="close" />
```

Important part is ***`cssClass="close-panel"`***.